# Android application to capture HFR video with time stamp?

Tags: android, image-processing, camera

I am currently using a Oneplus one device with cyanogenmod 11 and wish to use the device to measure short amounts of time captured on video (for example the swing of a pendulum).. Currently this is done by placing a stopwatch into the image, starting it, and then measuring the time by reading that stopwatch from the screen at the start and end of the interval. I am using the cyanogenmod camera application that offers the 120fps capture that I'd like to have

Clearly, this is quite unwieldy. Is there an application that can capture back camera images at the 120fps supported by hardware (or at least 60 frames per second or so), and time stamp them to the hundredth of a second?